# Is it worth the effort to empty a long string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, stringbuilder

I used a StringBuilder to write an SQL query in .NET.
After I perform the query, is there a point in manually setting the contents of the string to ""?

I'm guessing this is already being done by the compiler (maybe only with the optimize option enabled).

Comment: "I used a StringBuilder to write an SQL query in .NET" Sounds like you are concatenating parameters into your sql query. Don't do that! Instead use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection.

Comment: You don't give enough details for a definitive answer, but generally: No. Let the garbage collector handle it.

Comment: Setting anything to empty or even null doesn't do *anything* on the GC, so there's no benefit here.

Comment: I guess the `StringBuilder` is a local variable(which it should be), then there is no reason at all to empty it because the GC will clean it anyway. Setting it to null is also useless, that code will even be removed by the runtime.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've fixed it to now use Parameters. This is probably seperate question territory, but I have the name of the enviroment stored in a private const string in the same class and I paste it in the string like so: $"{databaseEnvironment}". In this case there is no input. Would this be a risk? In this case I'm only doing it to make the strings a bit more readable.

Comment: @Parrotmaster: What is `databaseEnvironment` for example? Why you think it could be a risk?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's just a private const string that I'm using to store the environment name. I'm specifically targeting the test environment atm and didn't wanna risk changing it on accident while changing the query.

Comment: Sounds like you should be changing the connection string instead to target a different database/instance/server

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you cannot set the contents of a string to "".  You cannot set the contents of a string to anything.  Strings in C# are immutable.

Perhaps what you meant to say is "is there a point in clearing the StringBuilder?"

In theory, there could be merit in clearing the StringBuilder, if:

- You are keeping that `StringBuilder` around and reusing it.
- You are filling it with huge strings. I mean, really huge. Like megabyte-long strings.

Under the above scenario, it might be worth clearing the `StringBuilder` after each use, instead of immediately before each reuse.

But you are probably not keeping the `StringBuilder` around, and even if you are, your SQL queries are probably not megabytes long, so ***stop worrying about this***.

And no, your guess is wrong, the compiler will not do anything about any of this, either with or without optimizations.  These are all affairs of the runtime, not of the compiler.

Comment: IMHO your claim "cannot set it to anything" is rather a misleaing statement, it seems to implicate that this is invalid `foo = "Hello World";`

Comment: @RandRandom you are right. I will fix this by reusing the exact terminology of the OP.

Comment: @RandRandom there, I fixed it.